# Virtualbox Ubuntu - How to make VirtualBox use host's internet

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, dns, proxy

Host: Windows7

Guest: Ubuntu via Virtualbox

So I have a proxy on my host because it's a computer at work. However, based on the .pac file that IE has listed, I THINK it requires specific origins for connections. So the IP on my host computer will work, but the one on my guest gets "Connection refused" (with the proxy off) and "403 permission error" (with the proxy on) from running wget.

With the proxy off I can make it so that DNS works, but stuff like browsing doesn't - in particular, I can ping, and dig, but browsing and wget don't work.

Been playing with this for a while, and the best I can do is get DNS working, which I'm thinking fails because the proxy specifies origin IPs. I've tried giving a user agent to wget with no success.

I've also tried setting up a bridged connection, but that didn't seem to work any better.

Comment: What settings have you tried for the "Attached to" network setting?  If you haven't already, you may want to try NAT.  VirtualBox should masquerade your outbound traffic to look like it's coming from your host instead of the guest.  This works much the same as home routers.  But if you need direct access to a guest's service, you may have to set up port forwarding.

Comment: Yes I've tried NAT, NatNetwork, Shared, Host-only, but have had little success. With NAT I was able to get access to the DNS using  `--natdnshostresolver1 on`, but was still unable to do wget and browsing.